# Grails GORM association unmapped exception

Tags: exception, grails, associations, grails-orm

I'm creating a Grails 2.4.3 app and have the following Domain classes:

```
class StockItem {
    String name
    BigDecimal wholesalePrice
    BigDecimal retailPrice
    BigDecimal profit

    static belongsTo = [ledger: Ledger]

    static constraints = {
        name minSize:3, maxSize:255
        wholesalePrice min:0.0, scale:2
        retailPrice min:0.0, scale:2
        retailPrice validator: { retailPrice, StockItem obj ->
            if (retailPrice < obj.wholesalePrice) {
                ['retailLessThanWholesale']
            }
        }
    }

    static mapping = { 
        profit(formula: 'RETAIL_PRICE - WHOLESALE_PRICE') 
    }
}

class Ledger {
    String name

    static hasMany = [clients: Client, invoices: Invoice, availableItems: StockItem, payments: Payment]

    static constraints = {
        name unique:true
    }
}
```

I have a unit test:

```
@Domain(StockItem)
@TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin)
class StockItemSpec extends Specification {
    void "Test profit calculation"() {
        when: "a stock item exists"
        StockItem i = new StockItem(name: "pencil", wholesalePrice: 1.50, retailPrice: 2.75)

        then: "profit is calculated correctly"
        i.profit == 1.25
    }
```

}

that is failing thusly:

```
Failure:  Test profit calculation(com.waldoware.invoicer.StockItemSpec)
|  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table stock_item refers to an unmapped class: com.waldoware.invoicer.Ledger
```

The app seems to be functioning OK, and I can't understand why this test is failing.  Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `belongsTo` association exists between your `StockItem` and `Ledger` domain classes, you will need to add `Ledger` to the `@Domain` annotation in your test:

```
@Domain([StockItem, Ledger])
```

This should properly configure the required domain classes when the unit test runtime is initialized. Depending on your other test cases, you may also need to include `Client` or `Payment` in the annotation.